# Nuxt webapp deployment through azure pipelines

Tags: vue.js, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuxt.js

i'm already thankfull for anyone reading this.
I've stumbled across some problems trying to deploy a Nuxt application in a correct way. For testing purposes i've created a clean installed Nuxt application so i'm sure nothing is wrong with my codebase. What my ultimate goal is is to push all my nuxt code to github which than gets picked up from a azure deployment pipeline and generates the needed build files and drops them to the webapp service and runs the needed start command. There's no documentation to be find about Azure which is really annoying for me. I'm not used to deploying stuff through a pipeline but need this to be working for this project.

Has anyone experience with Nuxt and deployments through Github -> Azure pipeline -> Build -> Web app running immediatly

What's i've tried already is pushing all the source code to a repository which get's picked up by azure pipeline. The only thing the pipeline does is paste the code in the wwwroot folder. Which is obviously not enough to make the application run automated.

What i expect is some insight from someone who is experienced with nuxt and azure deployments through github/bitbucket (doesn't really make a difference)

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your pipeline to build the nuxt files and deploy them. You can usually achieve the first step through npm commands, `npm install` then `npm run build`.

There's a few different ways to deploy them, which you'll have to decide between depending on your use case and environment. You can create an endpoint pointing to a CDN serving a blob, zip the built files and publish the artifact which is then used by a release pipeline, etc. Once the next files are created, you have all you need to deploy.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. I've already managed to get it deployed. It's a real pain. I'm a nodejs noob so to speak and i can't see to deploy it without a server framework. So now i'm using nuxt and express.